# Why does IE8 display a compatibility view button when IE9 doesn't?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, x-ua-compatible

On one of my sites, IE 8 is displaying the compatibility view button despite the presence of the X-UA-Compatible header. In IE 9, adding this header removes the button and sets the correct rendering mode, but why doesn't it do the same under IE 8?  If the user clicks the button in IE8, the site rendering breaks on several pages so how can I remove this button to stop them clicking it?

The site in question is [www.venuefinder.com](http://www.venuefinder.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your page is including the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Thus IE9 hides the button and IE8 doesn't understand it (since IE9 didn't exist when IE8 was shipping)

To ensure both IE8 and IE9 (and IE10) don't show the button you'd likely want to adjust your page to include a modern DOCTYPE

```
<!doctype html>
```

and set the meta tag to edge

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: No, but it can still understand the syntax of the tag presumably? That doesn't really explain why it can't understand to operate at "edge" level.

Comment: OK thanks, but the site is ancient (most of it written 10 years ago) and therefore I don't really want to use the HTML 5 doctype when the actual code isn't even vaguely correct for HTML 5. I was really just looking for a simple way to hide the button without changing the document mode, but if that's not possible I'll just have to put up with it how it is. :(

Comment: Use <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> This will ask any IE version to render the page with the latest IE version.
So IE7 will use IE7 mode, IE8 will use IE8, and IE9 will use IE9 mode.

Comment: the "HTML5 doctype" is a bit misleading... yes it is the current recommended doctype to use but it was chosen to ensure backwards compatibility... all it does is tells the browser that you are expecting to render in Standards Mode vs. Quirks mode.  What you have right now (4.01 traditional loose) will likely work fine too... at some point though I can see a newer browser trying to be "clever" and treat a well known decade old doctype based page in a "less than standards" way.

Comment: Note that the compatibility mode button won't disappear if you run your Web application through Visual Studio's internal Web server, it will only disappear if the application is run under IIS.